# mysql dynamically generated where clause

Tags: mysql

What's the correct usage when using OR in a select statement?
I have 3 columns that I want to use to filter the a search result:
 `Employee`, `Department`, `Date_Hired`

The query is a simple select

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,.... FROM table Where
Employee = "" OR
Department = "" OR
Date_Hired BETWEEN "" AND ""
```

What I'm trying to do is if the user just wants to filter the result using 
either of the 3 columns like for example if its like:

```
WHERE Employee = "Mickey"
OR Department = "" 
OR Date_Hired BETWEEN "" AND ""
```

Or if the user will also want to search for the date hired

```
WHERE Employee = "Mickey"
OR Department = "" 
OR Date_Hired BETWEEN "2014-01-01" AND "2014-01-31"
```

What's the proper way to use it?

Comment: What language are you using? How do you determine what the user wants to filter by?

Comment: You dynamically generate the string or bindings depending on permutation (as michael said, PHP JAVA whatever)

Comment: A great deal depends on the nature of the search. If the user wants to filter on employees named mickey hired within a date, that would be one combination, but employees named mickey OR those hired within a date is another.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate question tho

Comment: Check this out and all the links in its far right Related side of page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044497/dynamically-created-where-clause-php-mysql